# Assume draw that you draw a card from a standard deck.Find the probability of drawing a heart Given that your drew a face card (JQK)

Tags: probability

Assume draw that you draw a card from a standard deck.Find the probability of drawing a heart Given that your drew a face card (JQK)  Using probability formulas how do I figure this out 
Given in this equations mean what exactly??

Answer (score 0):

You know that you have drawn a Jack, Queen, or King and seek the probability that this card is also a Heart.

How many Jack, Queens, and Kings are there in the deck?   How many of these are Hearts?

Divide and calculate.

Comment: there are 12/52 faces which leave 3 of 13

Comment: @Linda You are dividing the wrong things. You need: $$\dfrac{\#\text{face card that are hearts}}{\#\text{face cards}}$$

Comment: So I divide 3/12 and simplified by 3 to get 1/4 or am I wrong I’m sorry I’m really trying to comprehend it

Comment: Yes, exactly.  There are **twelve** face cards, **three** among them are hearts, and *each* face card is *equally likely* to be the one you selected. So the (conditional) probability for obtaining a heart when you have selected a face card is: $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** Probability is generally, 
$$
P(\text{stuff})=\dfrac{\text{stuff you want}}{\text{total stuff}}
$$
(This is just a *rough* idea). Now you are restricting yourself to face cards because you knew you drew a face card, so this must be the 'total stuff' you are looking at. Now the only 'stuff' you want are hearts but they must be from the 'total stuff', i.e. face cards that are hearts. Can you see how this will give you $1/4$?

Comment: So that would mean I’m only looking at drawing the heart to get 1/4. Because that would  13/52  simplied to 1/4 right?

Comment: @Linda No, the 52 would mean your 'total stuff' is any card in the deck. But remember, you are restricting yourself to only face cards! How many face cards are there according to what you define to be a face card? That will be your total stuff. Then you want (the stuff you want) *have* to come from the total stuff, so they must be face cards. But you really want them to be hearts, because that's what you're interested in. So in the end, the stuff you want are the heart cards that are also face cards. So what does that make the numerator?

Answer (score 0):

There are two correct calculations here. I will add this answer to address

> Given in this equations mean what exactly??

The phrase "given whatever" means you are to assume "whatever" is true when you consider any further computations or other logical consequences. So

> Given that you drew a face card

tells you that as you proceed to find the probability that you have a heart you can assume the card you drew is one of JQK.

In this particular problem, knowing that you have a face card provides no information about the suit, since the face cards are equally distributed among the suits. That's why the probability of a heart is the same $1/4$ it would be if you drew a card and was not told anything about its value.

The technical term for this situation, which you will probably learn soon, is that the suit and the value are *independent*.